# Flask-oathlib: how to revoke a token

Tags: flask, flask-oauthlib

Reading the google docs (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi), it says i can revoke token (and thus force a login with credentials) by calling `credentials.revoke`.

What would be the flask-oathlib way to do this?

Comment: I tried  ```response = requests.get('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke',
                            params={'token': session.get('google_token')[0]}
    )``` but it doesn't force a authentication

Answer (score 0):

Flask-OAuthlib itself didn't provide a way to revoke token. (I'm the author of Flask-OAuthlib)

My new project [Authlib](https://authlib.org/) has provided a `revoke_token` method for OAuth 2.0. However, Google's revoke token endpoint doesn't respect RFC7009, which means the `revoke_token` method provided by Authlib can not be used.

You can send a HTTP request directly to revoke token endpoint:

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

BTW, if you need a RFC7009 revoke token method, checkout the source code in https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/client/oauth2.py